# jQuery or JS turn all words into italic type

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

```
var test = $('.text1').val();
var re = /\w+/g
$('.text3').html(test.replace(re, '<i>' + test.match(/\w+/g) + '</i>'));
```

if basic value like "Link text тест", then return "`<i>Link,text</i> <i>Link,text</i> тест`". But i need "`<i>Link</i> <i>text</i> текст`"

What can I do?

Comment: this is a job for CSS. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that this way?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you do,

```
body {
    font-style: italic; // add italic!important if you need to...
}
```

Your question isn't worded well.

Otherwise if it must be jquery or js then...

```
$("*").css("font-style", "italic");
```

That should also work.

Comment: That's not handling the regex matching though.

Comment: Text in the textarea, where there are also Cyrillic. I need to search all latin words and turn them into italic type.
Sorry for my english